# Hiding declaration in cpp file

Tags: c++, class, interface, namespaces

I have a file `decl.h` with the following:

```
namespace foo {
    ...
    class A;
    ...
}
```

I want to use the whole of declarations from `decl.h`, except for `class A`, as I want to have another class, with the same name, declared and defined inside my `def.cpp`. I'm looking for something that'd allow me to do this:

```
# include "decl.h"
using namespace foo;
hiding foo::A;

class A {
    ...
};
```

Is there anything like that? Or the only way around is to explicitly make each desired member from `foo` public in my `def.cpp`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't hide members of a namespace, and certainly not when using a `using namespace ...` statement.

The whole point of namespaces is to avoid naming conflicts like you describe.

So, get rid of the `using namespace foo;` statement, and wrap the second `class A` in a different namespace, eg:

```
#include "decl.h"
//using namespace foo;

namespace defcpp {

class A {
    ...
};

}
```

Now `def.cpp` will know about `foo::A` and `defcpp::A`.  You just have to qualify which one you want to use whenever you need to use an `A`.  For example:

```
#include "decl.h"
//using namespace foo;

namespace defcpp {

class A {
    ...
};

}

class B {
    defcpp::A a;
    ...
};

void doSomething()
{
    defcpp::A a;
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just remove `using namespace foo;`. That's the whole point of namespaces.

Comment: Sorry, the whole point of my post was to find something other than this solution -- as I stated in the question. I'm looking for some keyword or `delete ...;` combination I so far haven't been presented to.